# Deleting OUs in Active Directory Users and Computers

Tags: active-directory, ou

I need to delete few Organizational units in Active Directory users and computers that were created for testing purposes.

When I try to delete them, following error occurred:
“You don’t have sufficient privileges to delete TestDevs, or this object is protected from accidental deletion.”
I am logged on as domain admin and I guess I do have sufficient privileges to delete OU.

I tried to change properties of OU, but I don’t see anything except “General”, “Managed by” and “COM+” tab in OU properties – no options for un-protecting object from deletion.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To un-protect object from accidental deletion, you need to un-check proper box in “Object” tab in OU properties. In order to see this tab, you need to configure the ADUC by going to the View option on the toolbar, and then check “Advanced Features”.

This will add some new containers and tabs in OU properties. In “Object” tab in OU properties you will see check box “Protect object from accidental deletion” – un-check the box and you should be able to delete OU.